# How to record pid of job(s) launched in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, parallel-processing

I have a bash script that sends many jobs to a cluster, it looks something like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 ${MIN}`

do
  cd longjob_${i}/
  make
  nohup ./prog.x &
done
```

`prog.x` is a fortran executable. I would like to record the pid of each job, so I could
kill at will jobs when needed. Is there a way of doing this, for instance, recording the pid
number in the `nohup.out` file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the PID of a process started with nohup via ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647382/get-the-pid-of-a-process-started-with-nohup-via-ssh)

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$!` contains the PID of the last background job that was started:

```
for i in `seq 1 ${MIN}`
do
  cd longjob_${i}/
  make
  nohup ./prog.x &
  echo $! >> ~/pids.txt
done
```

Comment: Suppose that I sended the job without the line echo $! >> ~/pids.txt. Is there a way to retrieve the pids in this case?

Comment: You can use `ps` to find all your processes.